# GUI Setting is not working and missing - 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bug-reporting

I'm trying to change the format time and I found out that my setting GUI was gone. Even I want to use the display setting it doesn't show up when I'm trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reinstall my `gnome-control-center` and finally it works!

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```